# Como colocar o retorno do axios.get em uma variável?

Tags: javascript, promises, async-await

fiz um acesso ao banco de dados e com o axios.get peguei o retorno mas preciso armazenar esse retorno em uma variável para que possa usar mais pra frente, mas ao tentar obtive como resultado: Promise { : "pending" }, segue o código do que estou tentando fazer abaixo:

```
async function obterLocalizacao() {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:3333/informacoes')
        .then(response => { return response })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

console.log(obterLocalizacao());
```

A dúvida é, como armazenar o valor de response em outra variável para usar futuramente?

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem?
Quando é feito uma requisição, isso não é nada mais do que uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), como voce está retornando o valor de uma função assincronia sempre é uma promise, então sua função também retorna uma promise, então o que você deverá fazer é algo bem parecido com isto.

```
 function getLocais() {
        return fetch('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/regioes');
    }
```

e então para utilizar o retorno desta função, é algo como isto

```
const r = await getLocais();
```

E você poderá utilizar o valor desta váriavel.
Para tratar o retorno você pode fazer algo mais legal como isto:

```
async function getLocais() {
  try {
    const r = await fetch('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/regioes');
    return r;
  } catch (e) {
    return null
  }
}
```

E você pode fazer mais alterações do que algo trivial como apenas uma requisição.

Lembre-se, uma função 'async' sempre retorna uma promise, então você deverá ou utilizar o `then` e o `catch` para pegar seu valor, o utilizar o `await` junto com o `try/catch` caso queira tratar o resultado